# Defining custom route in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a MVC3 application in which I want to modify the routes as follows:

```
public class DealsController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult View()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Add(DealViewModel newDeal)
    {
        // Code to add the deal to the db
    }
}
```

What I would like to do is when a  user requests **www.domain.com/deals/view** I want to rewrite the url as **www.doamin.com/unsecure/deals/view**. So any route which does not have the Authorize attribute needs to be modified by adding the word unsecure.

**Note:** I have several controllers in my application so I am looking for a solution which can handle this in a generic fashion.

Comment: Why don't you use IIS 7.0's UrlRewrite

Comment: has anything helped you? or have abandon this question?

Answer (score 0):

Map to routes to one DealsController and use RedirectToAction if it's allowed to execute controller from such url.

Answer (score 0):

Please use RedirectToAction for it

Example :

```
return RedirectToAction( new RouteValueDictionary( 
    new { controller = "unsecure/deals", action = "view" } ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a custom route just do this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "unsecure", // Route name
            "unsecure/{controller}/{action}/{id}"
        );
```

be sure to add this **before** your default map

that should work. I didn't test it.

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 separate controllers:

```
public class UnsecureDealsController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult View()
    {
        return View();
    }
}

public class SecureDealsController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Add(DealViewModel newDeal)
    {
        // Code to add the deal to the db
    }

    public ActionResult View()
    {
        return RedirectToAction("View", "UnsecureDeals");
    }
}
```

And then route like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(null, 
    "unsecure/deals/{action}/{id}",
    new
    {
        controller = "UnsecureDeals",
        action = "Index", 
        id = UrlParameter.Optional
    }); 

routes.MapRoute(null, 
    "deals/{action}/{id}",
    new
    {
        controller = "SecureDeals",
        action = "Index", 
        id = UrlParameter.Optional
    });

// the other routes come BEFORE the default route
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: I do not want to split my controllers based on what is secure/unsecure actions.

Comment: I do not want you to split your URL's based on what is secure/unsecure actions. Why is this necessary?